# How to determine if the following series converges and also absolutely converges?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k_n}}{n} \text{where}\ k_{n} =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  &  n=3m\mbox{ }(m\in\mathbb{N}) \\
  2  &  \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$$

I need to determine if this series converges and also converges absolutely. I know that it equals to the sum of 3 diverging series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n-2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n}$ but it doesn't help because it doesn't mean that the whole series diverges... Hints?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{3n-1}-\frac{1}{3n}\gt 0$.

Comment: So I'm getting a sum of a diverging serise and converging serise and therefore the original serise diverges... nice thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(3N)$ be the sum up to $3N$. Since $\frac{1}{3n-1}-\frac{1}{3n}\gt 0$, we have
$$S(3N)\gt 1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{3N-2}.\tag{1}$$
But the sum on the right of (1) is $\gt \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots +\frac{1}{3N}$. Now use the fact that the harmonic series diverges.